# Regex cutting down a specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this HTML tag `<a href="abc> google </a>`, how can i put the **"** after the letter **c** using regular expression

HTML: `<a href="abc> google </a>`

Regex: `/\=\s*["“'”](.*?)[^“"'”]\s*\>/g`

Replace: ="$1">

https://regex101.com/r/1FQods/1

https://jsfiddle.net/liev04/6n038nvm/

[image: regex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
str.replace(/=\s*["']([^"']*?)\s*?(?=>)/g,'="\1"');
```

This should work also in cases where the second `"` exists already. It also allows for blanks between the `=` and the beginning of the string.

See here for a demo: https://regex101.com/r/xo52ka/1

Another issue might be cases like:

```
<a href="abc def > google </a>
```

My Solution will turn that into

```
<a href="abc def"> google </a>
```

But, of course, this solution has its limitations and is by far not *watertight*. It will only work on the *last* attribute of each tag (because of the lookahead `(?=>)` in the regexp).

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
str.replace(/href="[^\s>"]+/, function(match) { return match+'"' });
```

Comment: Actually this worked i'm making some tests to see, i didn't understand how the match variable is filled but thanks

Comment: A nice and short solution. Unfortunately, it will fail in cases where a second `"` is already in place like in `<a href= "abc"> google </a>`. This would be changed into `<a href="abc""> google </a>`

Comment: Good spot. I'd think of a fix except your answer covers it already.